# Insert Default Table Content into SQLite Database on Creation

Tags: php, sqlite

After hours of trying to find a clear solution here @Stack, gave up and hope to get some input. I admit, not proficient with SQLite so forgive my stupidity...

Using a simple SQLite tutorial @ https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/12212/sqlite-3-database-encryption.html

*Note that tutorial using OPENSSL for encryption*.

The creation of the database + table is simple and straight forward.

Issue we are having is inserting default table content **IF the table is empty** *but NOT overwite existing data*.

In other words, when dbconfig.php is called:

```
<?php
//Create a new SQLite3 Database
$db = new SQLite3('members.db');

//Create a new table to our database 
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members (firstname STRING, lastname STRING, address STRING, key STRING)";
$db->exec($query);

?>
```

Need to insert default table content like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members (firstname,lastname,address,key) VALUES ('Jane','Doe','New York','key')";

//Create a new SQLite3 Database
$db = new SQLite3('members.db');

//Create a new table to our database 
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members (firstname STRING, lastname STRING, address STRING, key STRING)";

$query = "INSERT INTO members (firstname,lastname,address,key) VALUES ('Jane','Doe','New York','key')";

$db->exec($query);
```

The above does not insert upon table creation. Even if it did, seems like would overwrite existing data.

Have also tried:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members (firstname,lastname,address,key) VALUES ('Jane','Doe','New York','key')";

//Create a new SQLite3 Database
$db = new SQLite3('members.db');

//Create a new table to our database 
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members (firstname STRING, lastname STRING, address STRING, key STRING)";

$query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO members (firstname,lastname,address,key) VALUES ('Jane','Doe','New York','key')";

$db->exec($query);
```

A fellow teacher asked how to do this at tutorial site but no answer. Really trying to get a project completed before school starts back. Need some help, please:)

Comment: Is that your complete code? Because you're never executing the create table query, you're just assigning a new value to the `$query` variable and then executing that one.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that is far as we have gotten. Unfortunately neither of us have ever dealt with sqlite (or mysql) very much. In a learning pattern at this point:)